# I keep getting Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to make my navbar sticky when it gets to a certain section of my website but my intersectionObserverApi isn't working. I think it has something to do with my useRefs being null when I try to select the section element I want to observe.I have tried selecting them using querySelector but didn't work either.
This is in React btw any help would be appreciated.

Here is my component:

```
import { React, useRef } from "react";
import "./About.css";
import Image from "../Images/7F1E6503-0880-4C1A-B2E8-070D0FAE543B.jpg";

const About = () => {
    const aboutSectionRef = useRef("");
    console.log(aboutSectionRef); // getting object with key value pair of current: ''
    const el = aboutSectionRef.current;
    console.log(el); // I'm getting null in the console.log
    function stickyNavBar(entries, observer) {
        console.log(entries);
    }
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        const sectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(stickyNavBar, {
            root: null,
            threshold: 0.1,
        });

        sectionObserver.observe(el);
    });

    // const aboutSectionRef = useRef(null);

    // document.addEventListener(
    //  "DOMContentLoaded",
    //
    // );

    return (
        <section
            ref={aboutSectionRef}
            id="about-section"
            className="about-section aboutsectionref"
        >
            <img className="headshot" src={Image} alt="pic of Osman" />
            <h1>Nice to meet you</h1>
            <p>
                Over the past 2 years I have embarked on a journey that has undoubtedly
                <span className="blue"> challenged</span> me like never before when I
                decided to start
                <span className="blue"> learning</span> how to code. I am a{" "}
                <span className="blue"> self-taught</span> web developer with{" "}
                <span className="blue"> passion</span> and{" "}
                <span className="blue"> determination</span> for anything I set my mind
                to.
            </p>
            <h2>Attributes I bring to the team</h2>
            <div className="two-uls">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-1x"></i> Open-Minded
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-1x"></i> Team Player
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-1x"></i> Drive to
                        self-improve
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-1x"></i> Time Management
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-1x"></i> Communication
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <i className="fa-solid fa-circle-check fa-1x"></i> Attention to
                        detail
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default About;
```

Comment: `I'm getting null in the console.log` that's the problem, you can't `.observe(null)`

Comment: Can you help me understand why that is and how to fix that please